# find the almost identical cells in a range

Tags: excel, google-sheets

i am looking for a formula or something like that to find the most nearest or almost identical values in a range of google spreadsheet.
for example look at the following values of different cells.
3,5,13,18,19,20,21,26,28,52,62,75
I want a result like this group of value (18,19,20,21) 
because in that range, only these values has the least difference to each of them.

if it is possible then please help..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your range of values always sorted in ascending order? If not are you looking only at the least difference between adjacent cells in the range? Can your data contain multiple result ranges? eg if  the 75 in your example was replaced by 63 then there would be a second result group of (62, 63). Will the least difference always be 1 or could it be some other value (such as 0 or 2 or 0.5)?

Comment: thanks for the reply,
in case of situation like this where another group of (62,63) comes in the result then still we give the priority to the group of (18,19,20,21) because they are more in quantity.
in other words if 2 people are saying something and 4 are saying another  then i'll go with 4 people.
i hope it is clear now.

Comment: What about the several other questions asked? These are aimed at defining an unambiguous definition of the problem you are trying to solve. Without a precise definition of the problem how can you hope to be offered a satisfactory solution?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Ul6Ky16t234JqB_phwob-ucLGbISW-datpcSYEzb38/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

Place the values in column **A** and sort them.  Then in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A2-A1<=1,"Good","")
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(A3-A2<=1,A2-A1<=1),"Good","")
```

and copy down.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the difference could be any value, for example i have another set of values (30,50,130,180,190,200,210,260,280,520,620,750) so now that formula would not help much, i hope you understand the issue. thanks anyway.

Comment: @BhupendraGhanghoriya  start with ***1***    and pick a larger value if necessary.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Ul6Ky16t234JqB_phwob-ucLGbISW-datpcSYEzb38/edit#gid=0